# How to speed Meteor.js build times?

Tags: meteor

When I make a change to Javascript file and save it, it takes over 5 seconds to build and restart the development server even if it is simple 10 line example app. I am new to Meteor.js so I don't know if it's normal, but I though changes should appear instantly (about a second or two) on a browser? 5-6 seconds feels pretty long time for me.

Selecting package versions and downloading packages seem to take the major part of the time.

There is one websocket pending (Chrome Dev tools Network tab) when it's restarting. I'm using Meteor 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

That's a known problem they're working on. You can read about it and follow the progress in issue [#2846](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2846).

Comment: I thought Meteor had LiveReload / Hot swapping / Hot Code Push / whatever ? This would mean you shouldn't have to rebuild given one file change. I am confused about this.

Comment: This problem is still lying around, end of 2015... Frightening?

Comment: It's 2016 and my builds are 30 seconds on a SSD w/ 500 mb/s reads.

Comment: That issue is closed, but there are some open ones here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues?q=milestone%3A%22Tool+Performance+and+Stability%22

Answer (score 0):

There is a new issue about this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4284

Upgrading to a pre-release of 1.3 seems one of the best options right now:

`meteor update --release METEOR@1.3-modules-beta.8`

And upgrading to 1.3 when it comes out (should come around march-april 2016).

---

Quick measurements to get a rough idea:

BryanARivera [says on the thread](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4284#issuecomment-183770930) that updating to `1.3-modules-beta.8` gets him `From 6-10s to 1-2s.`

I tried on the https://github.com/wekan/wekan project by changing a view component (on an early-2013 mbp with SSD):

```
with `METEOR@1.2.1`                    ~10s to reload
with `METEOR@1.2.2-faster-rebuilds.0`  ~5s  to reload
with `METEOR@1.3-modules-beta.8`       ~4s  to reload
```

Comment: What spec of machine are you getting these rebuild times on?

Comment: @timebandit This is a macbook pro 2013 with i7, 16GB ram and SSD. I haven't tried with meteor 1.4 that is supposed to improve build times.

Answer (score 0):

This was my purely hardware solution to the problem of **slow Meteor build times**.

When I decided to get into development I was adamant that I wasn't going to run out and buy the latest and greatest in hardware until I actually knew how to code and knew what my requirements were in the long term.

So I went out and bought a used **15" Acer laptop**; it had the following spec:

- **Memory**: 6Gb RAM
- **Processor**: Intel Pentium CPu 6200 @ 2.13GHz *2
- **OS**: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 32-bit
- **Storage**: 153.5GB HDD

[image: Asus Laptop]

With this setup I saw rebuild times of between **15s ~ 30s** (including the browser refresh) of a side project using Meteor 1.4, **React**and a **Mongo db** instance with around 1500 records. I found these times to be excruciatingly slow when it came to making multiple changes. You can see the initial version of the project I was working on here[here](http://islamiccharities.org.uk).

After trying to get work done in cafe's and libraries I realised that I was much happier working at home, and once the side project was complete I decided I would reward myself with an upgrade.

My initial choices were between a [Macbook Pro](https://www.apple.com/uk/macbook-pro/specs/) and a gaming PC such as the [Asus ROG](https://www.asus.com/Tower-PCs/ROG-G20CB/), but since the former are very expensive and the later's graphics abilities were of no use to me (I'm not a gamer) I ruled them both out. These being quality machines, when I compared them against reviews of other PC's and laptops I noticed that where other systems scored higher in performance, they were lower in build quality and vice versa and there was no overall winner that had me sold.

I decided, a self build was in order and that it would be great if I could fit it all into a [mini-ITX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-ITX) board and case. My requirements became:

- An SSD drive (faster read/write times than a HDD)
- Ubuntu: On account of it being free and [faster that MacOS](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=osx10_ubuntu1410&num=1)
- Mini-ITX: so that it can unobtrusively fit onto my desk
- Quite
- 16Gb DDR4 RAM: this seems the bare minimum for development.

After some searching I came across these instructions for a [$682 Skylake Mac Mini Hackintosh Build](https://youtu.be/GRX-6rWkuzk), which formed the basis of my build.

As I currently have no intention of working with **MacOS**, as per the Hackintosh instructions, I did not change the Wifi card.

My new spec list along with what I paid for each item were as follows:

- [Intel Core i7 Quad-Core i7-6700 3.4GHz Processor](http://amzn.to/2techGT)    **£279.97**
- [Crucial Ballistix Sport 16 GB kit (8 GB x 2) DDR4 2400MT/s UDIMM 288-Pin Memory](http://amzn.to/2sJn3l9)    **£121.00**
- [Samsung 850 Pro 250GB SSD](http://amzn.to/2sJHrT9) **£121.00**
- [Gigabyte H-170 Motherboard](http://amzn.to/2sJteW7)    **£109.00**
- [Noctua NH-L9i CPU Cooler](http://amzn.to/2sJndZN)  **£35.00**
- [External PicoPSU Power Brick](http://amzn.to/2sJtoNd)  **£24.00**
- [MiniBox 160W PicoPSU](http://amzn.to/2uH4mzF)  **£40.00**
- [Streacom F1C-WS](http://amzn.to/2tNGJJl)   **£90.00**
- [Noctua NF-A4x10 FLX](http://amzn.to/2uHhvch) **£10.99**

Making a total spend of **£830** (correct at time of writing).

[image: New development PC]

The case comes in two finishes; black and silver, I went with the former to keep my monitor my main point of focus on my desk. It took me about an hour as a newbie to put it all together. I imagine it would be much faster if I did this for living.

Pros:

- My rebuild times were drastically reduced to only 2s using Meteor 1.4.
- The PC as a whole takes only 15 seconds to boot up whereas the laptop could take as long as 2 minutes.
- With the laptop, a Meteor reload would fully load the CPU whereas with the PC the 4 cores barley rose above a few percent, as viewed from the System Monitor tool.
- It has a footprint of 19cm x 19cm making which is smaller than my laptop.
- It was super quite, the fans were barley noticeable on most days.

Cons:

- The draw back of such a small case is that there is no room for a graphics card should I want to start gaming in the future.
- All the ports are at the rear. However, this does give the front a clean look.
- There is no reset button but the power switch can be configured via the bios to act as a "soft" switch such that, pressing it brings up a dialogue giving you the option to restart/suspend/shutdown.

Conclusion:

Overall I am very happy with the choice of components I made and the money I saved by self-building.The PC is powerful enough for video editing and I am working towards editing my first Youtube tutorials.

Being more wise about my needs means that I am now using **Docker** to create isolated development environments to prevent software conflicts which in themselves can chew up time in resolving.

The component research I did means that I am aware of the massive progress that PC cases, coolers, cables, memory cards, fans have made since I left college. You can now build something not only small and powerful but also attractive with options like [tempered glass](http://amzn.to/2sJYvIG), [liquid coolers](http://amzn.to/2tO0CjJ), custom [braided cables](http://amzn.to/2tehuyu), [case strobe lighting](http://amzn.to/2tmSd3G) and [shaped cases](http://amzn.to/2tn54CP).